# django+nginx+gunicorn issues with Cerbot to turn into HTTPS

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, https, debian

I am currently deploying my django app on a server **AWS Lightsail Debian 10.8**. It's working fine with http. So I wnated to turn my app into HTTPS and getting an SSL certificate. I followed 2 tutorials about it :

- [This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYdv6pkCufk)
- [This page](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=debianbuster)

Once all these steps done nothing works anymore even in HTTP, the site isn't accessible... Here is the config file in /etc/nginx/sites-available.

```
 server {
  server_name 13.38.76.96 www.zlochteam.com;

 location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.zlochteam.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.zlochteam.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

 server {
    if ($host = www.zlochteam.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name 13.38.76.96 www.zlochteam.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I wanted to know if someone has ecountered the same issue and how he solved it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Resolved

I just had to allow connection from the port 443 on AWS LightSail, such a dummy error...

Here is where you need to add the HTTPS connection, in the Networking tab.

[image: AWS LightSail Networking part]

Answer (score 2):

Before you run the commands in [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=debianbuster), make sure you have the following in your Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 13.38.76.96 www.zlochteam.com;
    listen [::]:80;
    ...
```

Seems like certbot now requires the ipv6 as well.

Comment: Thanks, just by adding the 2 lines at the beginning of my inital file it should work ?

Comment: Yes.  Do that with the original file (not the one that Certbot will generate).  *Then* run the certbot instructions.  Then you should try the suggestions given by Aleksey.  `nginx -t` to test it, etc...

Comment: Thanks the issue was very far from this, I just had to allow port 443 on LightSail AWS... Dummy error sorry...

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Http has break because the certbot added the redirect `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

You should test config by command `nginx -t` and then reload config `nginx -s reload`.

Comment: I need to do something with the redirect ? (I am quite new with the 'prod' world)
I ran the 2 command you gave me and it indicates success

Comment: Check your website is responsible on http://www.zlochteam.com:8000/

Comment: Thanks the issue was very far from this, I just had to allow port 443 on LightSail AWS... Dummy error sorry...